# Tomcat 9 starting issue getting bellow issue copied bootstract and tomcat-juli and wraper jars on catalina home

Tags: tomcat9

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager;

```
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.<clinit>(Digester.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.createStartDigester(Catalina.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:469)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:550)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```